# How to separate the brightness setting on an LED P10? Arduino

Tags: arduino

I wish to separate data transmission from light control. Data transmission will be conducted using an Arduino UNO, while light control will be managed using an Arduino Nano.

Schematics:

[image]

However, after assembling the circuit, my P10 LED display cannot have its brightness adjusted and appears dim. What could be the issue?

Code Untuk Arduino UNO dan Arduino Nano:

```
/*
  Quick demo of major drawing operations on a single DMD
 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <DMD2.h>
#include <fonts/SystemFont5x7.h>
#include <fonts/Arial_Black_16.h>

SoftDMD dmd(1,1);  // DMD controls the entire display

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  dmd.selectFont(Arial_Black_16);
  dmd.begin();
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  dmd.setBrightness(50);
  dmd.fillScreen(true);
  delay(1000);
  dmd.clearScreen();
  delay(1000);

  dmd.setBrightness(100);
  dmd.fillScreen(true);
  delay(1000);
  dmd.clearScreen();
  delay(1000);

  dmd.setBrightness(150);
  dmd.fillScreen(true);
  delay(1000);
  dmd.clearScreen();
  delay(1000);

  dmd.setBrightness(200);
  dmd.fillScreen(true);
  delay(1000);
  dmd.clearScreen();
  delay(1000);

  dmd.setBrightness(250);
  dmd.fillScreen(true);
  delay(1000);
  dmd.clearScreen();
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: what's a `LED P10`?

Comment: Could you provide more info on the display? A datasheet and/or a picture of the backside would be helpful!

Comment: @jsotola https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbigscreen.my%2Fled-display-module%2Fp10-outdoor-led%2F&psig=AOvVaw3L0ZIgYFWhujQeT51ixaTa&ust=1701924794797000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBEQjRxqFwoTCPiupIiC-oIDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE

Comment: @HansmitmFlammenwerfer https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbigscreen.my%2Fled-display-module%2Fp10-outdoor-led%2F&psig=AOvVaw3L0ZIgYFWhujQeT51ixaTa&ust=1701924794797000&source=images&cd=vfe&opi=89978449&ved=0CBEQjRxqFwoTCPiupIiC-oIDFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE

Comment: But, the problem is solved. It's GND issue, thankyouu